# Attributes of XML node using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

Is there a way to get the name of an attribute of an XML node using javascript.
Lets take this as a sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>     
        <Count name="EmployeeCount">100</Count>
        <employee id="9999" >Harish</employee>
        <Salary>
            <year id="2000">50 Grands</year>
            <year id="2001">75 Grands</year>    
            <year id="2002">100 Grands</year>
        </Salary>
    </Employees>
```

I am loading XML using ActiveXObject.As you can see not all elements have attributes.I need to list all attributes like

```
name
id
id
id
id
```

Comment: As I understand you need list all attributes but in the example you post "EmployeeCount" wich is the value of the attribute "name"... not the attribute itself... if I'm correct the output should be:

name
id
id
id
id

right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nodes = xml.selectNodes("//@*")
for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    alert(nodes[i].nodeName);
}
```